# Native-activity sample crashes on GalaxyS3 Android 4.3

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-camera, native

I tried running the OpenCV4Android "native-activity" sample on my Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3 and I immediately get a crash. I can successfully run the "tutorial-1-camerapreview" sample project, so I'm pretty sure I set up OpenCV4Android correctly.

Here is most of the logcat output:

```
02-13 11:53:29.165: I/OCVSample::Activity(25745): Instantiated new class org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity.CvNativeActivity
02-13 11:53:29.626: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Service connection created
02-13 11:53:29.626: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Trying to get library path
02-13 11:53:29.776: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Trying to get library list
02-13 11:53:29.896: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Library list: ""
02-13 11:53:29.896: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): First attempt to load libs
02-13 11:53:29.896: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Trying to init OpenCV libs
02-13 11:53:29.896: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Trying to load library /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so
02-13 11:53:29.896: D/dalvikvm(25745): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so 0x42794758
02-13 11:53:30.307: D/dalvikvm(25745): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so 0x42794758
02-13 11:53:30.307: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): OpenCV libs init was ok!
02-13 11:53:30.307: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): First attempt to load libs is OK
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.8 =====================================
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Version control:               2.4.8
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Platform:
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Host:                        Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Target:                      Linux 1 armv7-a
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     CMake:                       2.8.12
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     CMake generator:             Ninja
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Configuration:               Release
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   C/C++:
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C++ Compiler:                /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  (ver 4.6)
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C Compiler:                  /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Precompiled headers:         NO
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   OpenCV modules:
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     To be built:                 core androidcamera flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml objdetect video contrib photo java dynamicuda legacy gpu ocl stitching videostab
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Disabled:                    ts world
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Disabled by dependency:      -
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Unavailable:                 nonfree python superres facedetect imuvstab tegra vstab
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Android: 
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Android ABI:                 armeabi-v7a with NEON
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     STL type:                    gnustl_static
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Native API level:            android-9
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     SDK target:                  android-11
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Android NDK:                 /opt/android-ndk-r8c (toolchain: arm-linux-androideabi-4.6)
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     android tool:                /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android (Android SDK Tools, revision 22.)
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Google Play package:         YES
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Android examples:            YES
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   GUI: 
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     GTK+ 2.x:                    NO
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     GThread :                    NO
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     GtkGlExt:                    NO
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     OpenGL support:              NO
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Media I/O: 
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     ZLib:                        z (ver 1.2.3)
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
02-13 11:53:30.307: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Video I/O:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     AndroidNativeCamera:         YES, use prebuilt libraries
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Other third-party libraries:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use IPP:                     NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.1.2)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.1 interface 6102)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use OpenMP:                  NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use GCD                      NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use Concurrency              NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use C=:                      NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 6.0)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use OpenCL:                  YES
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   NVIDIA CUDA
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use CUFFT:                   YES
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     NVIDIA GPU arch:             32
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     NVIDIA PTX archs:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use fast math:               NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   OpenCL:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Version:                     dynamic
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Include path:                /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Python:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.3)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Java:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Java tests:                  NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Documentation:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Build Documentation:         YES
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Sphinx:                      /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build (ver 1.1.3)
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Tests and samples:
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Tests:                       NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     Performance tests:           NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):     C/C++ Examples:              NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   Install path:                  /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/build/builds/o4t/install
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/build/builds/o4t
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): -----------------------------------------------------------------
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): General configuration for OpenCV4Tegra =====================================
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   inner version                  2.4.8
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   memory allocator               YES
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   hardware link                  YES
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   compact sources                YES
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745):   logging enabled                NO
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): -----------------------------------------------------------------
02-13 11:53:30.317: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Init finished with status 0
02-13 11:53:30.317: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Unbind from service
02-13 11:53:30.317: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(25745): Calling using callback
02-13 11:53:30.317: I/OCVSample::Activity(25745): OpenCV loaded successfully
02-13 11:53:30.317: D/dalvikvm(25745): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity-1/libnative_activity.so 0x42794758
02-13 11:53:30.317: D/dalvikvm(25745): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity-1/libnative_activity.so 0x42794758
02-13 11:53:30.317: D/dalvikvm(25745): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity-1/libnative_activity.so 0x42794758, skipping init
02-13 11:53:30.637: I/Choreographer(25745): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-13 11:53:32.639: V/threaded_app(25745): Creating: 0x5fd43e90
02-13 11:53:32.639: V/threaded_app(25745): Config: mcc=310 mnc=410 lang=en cnt=US orien=2 touch=3 dens=320 keys=1 nav=1 keysHid=3 navHid=0 sdk=18 size=2 long=2 modetype=1 modenight=1
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): Start: 0x5fd43e90
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): activityState=10
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): Resume: 0x5fd43e90
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): activityState=11
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): InputQueueCreated: 0x5fd43e90 -- 0x6021a6e0
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): APP_CMD_INPUT_CHANGED
02-13 11:53:32.649: V/threaded_app(25745): Attaching input queue to looper
02-13 11:53:32.659: I/Choreographer(25745): Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-13 11:53:32.689: V/threaded_app(25745): NativeWindowCreated: 0x5fd43e90 -- 0x5bba12a0
02-13 11:53:32.689: V/threaded_app(25745): APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW
02-13 11:53:32.689: V/threaded_app(25745): WindowFocusChanged: 0x5fd43e90 -- 1
02-13 11:53:32.689: I/OCV:libnative_activity(25745): APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW
02-13 11:53:32.689: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): CvCapture_Android::CvCapture_Android(0)
02-13 11:53:32.689: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): Library name: libopencv_java.so
02-13 11:53:32.689: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): Library base address: 0x5f336000
02-13 11:53:32.749: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): Libraries folder found: /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/
02-13 11:53:32.749: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=/data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: E/OpenCV::camera(25745): ||libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
02-13 11:53:32.759: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so'
02-13 11:53:32.949: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so, dlerror="dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android17IConsumerListenerD2Ev" referenced by "libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so"..."
02-13 11:53:32.949: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so'
02-13 11:53:32.959: D/OpenCV::camera(25745): Loaded library '/data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so'
02-13 11:53:32.959: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): CameraHandler::initCameraConnect(0x5f9f88cd, 0, 0x6021a938, 0x0)
02-13 11:53:32.959: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Current process name for camera init: org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity
02-13 11:53:33.800: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Instantiated new CameraHandler (0x5f9f88cd, 0x6021a938)
02-13 11:53:33.800: I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): initCameraConnect: [anti-shake=0;antibanding=60hz;antibanding-values=off,50hz,60hz,auto;auto-exposure=center;auto-exposure-lock-supported=false;auto-exposure-values=center,matrix,spot;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=false;cam_mode=-1;camera-mode=-1;chk_dataline=0;denoise=denoise-on;denoise-values=denoise-off,denoise-on;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize,whiteboard,blackboard,aqua,emboss,sketch,neon,washed,vintage-warm,vintage-cold,point-blue,point-red-yellow,point-green,cartoonize;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.166667;face-detection=off;face-detection-values=off,on;face_beauty=-1;flash-mode=off;flash-mode-values=off,on,auto,torch;focal-length=3.7;focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);focus-distances=0.15,1.20,Infinity;focus-mode=auto;focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,fixed,continuous-picture,continuous-video;front-hflip=0;hdr-mode=-1;hfr-size-values=800x480,640x480;histogram=disable;histogram-values=enable,disable;horizontal-view-angle=59.6;intelligent-mode=0;i
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Cameras: (null)
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Picture Sizes: 3264x2448,3264x2176,3264x1836,2048x1536,2048x1152,1600x1200,1280x960,1280x720,960x720,640x480
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Picture Formats: jpeg,raw
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Preview Sizes: 1920x1080,1280x720,960x720,800x480,720x480,640x480,576x432,480x320,352x288,320x240,240x160,176x144
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Preview Formats: yuv420sp,yuv420sp-adreno,yuv420p,yuv420p,nv12
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Preview Frame Rates: 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Thumbnail Sizes: 512x288,480x288,432x288,512x384,352x288,176x144,0x0
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Whitebalance Modes: auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Effects: none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize,whiteboard,blackboard,aqua,emboss,sketch,neon,washed,vintage-warm,vintage-cold,point-blue,point-red-yellow,point-green,cartoonize
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Scene Modes: auto,action,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,theatre,beach,snow,sunset,steadyphoto,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight,flowers,AR,back-light,text,fall-color,dusk-dawn
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Focus Modes: auto,infinity,macro,fixed,continuous-picture,continuous-video
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Antibanding Options: off,50hz,60hz,auto
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): Supported Flash Modes: off,on,auto,torch
02-13 11:53:33.810: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): initCameraConnect: autofocus is set to mode "continuous-video"
02-13 11:53:33.820: D/OpenCV_NativeCamera(25745): initCameraConnect: preview format is set to yuv420sp
02-13 11:53:33.820: A/libc(25745): @@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by tmalloc_small
02-13 11:53:33.820: A/libc(25745): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 25788 (.NativeActivity)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the libraries libnative_camera_rx.x.x.so files in your libs folder? there should be 6-7 .so files

Comment: OpenCV native camera might not work for some devices. Maybe you should use Java Camera samples instead if that is no a big problem.

Comment: @Darshan yes, even as noted in logs, it successfully loaded libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so.